# Powershell script for Firefox

Tags: firefox, powershell, scripting

I was wondering if anyone knew how to create a powershell script to automatically open certain webpages.

Such as google.com facebook.com and live.com

I already know how to do this for Internet explorer but need to do some testing on firefox too.

I know for IE its:

```
`$navOpenInBackgroundTab = 0x1000;
$ie = new-object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.Navigate2("https://www.google.com");
$ie.Navigate2("https://www.facebook.com", $navOpenInBackgroundTab);
$ie.Visible = $true;`
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776586/open-a-url-in-firefox-via-powershell

Comment: @Micky Balladelli
This is similar but I was looking for a similar format of coding as shown above.
Will try the link answer.
Thanks

Comment: Yes that is limited, I'm not aware of a Powershell to Firefox interface.

Answer (score 0):

start firefox.exe "  "

Copy the above into powershell or ISE and it should open firefox and the websites into seperate tabs.